# Anylogic: Sort agents in a collection by a parameter of the agents

Tags: java, collections, simulation, anylogic, agent

I am working on a siumulation of last mile delivery with multiple deliveries by truck. In order to make the shortest routing I'm working with an external program which optimize the order of the deliveries which output of the program sort the delivers by a number. I save this and input it in anylogic by a parameter called deliveryOrder in my Order agent.

When I create the truck agent and pick the orders by a pickup block, I store the orders agents in a collection inside each truck called route for the multiple delivery.

My biggest concern is when I want to sort the order agents inside route collection of everytruck by deliveryOrder ascending. I could not understand if i can sort agents in a collection with the parameter deliveryOrder. How can i do this?

[pickup block where i want to sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PRGv.png)

[van parameters and collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZEt4.png)

[order parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb8az.png)

I read the anylogic help but I couldnt figure it out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
route = (ArrayList<Order>)sortAscending( route, o -> o.deliveryOrder );
```

A few notes:

- sortAscending will return a new sorted list, so be sure to say route = sortAscending.  I made the mistake more than once of just saying sortAscending( collection, value ) and being surprised when my list did not sort.
- sortAscending will return a list, and a collection on the AnyLogic canvas will be an ArrayList, LinkedHashMap, or something more specific than just List, so you need to cast.
- your collection of route needs to specify that it is items of type order, or else java doesn't know that the o in the value express is an order and it cannot see o.deliveryOrder

Comment: Thans for the answer! now i can undestand how it works and I managed to finish the simulation!